# New Vegas - How useful is high stealth really?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I'm rather new to FA:NV (but not the series). I'm going for a pretty standard sniper build. Sneak around and pick of target. A bit like a stealth archers in Skyrim.

However, one guide suggests that you shouldn't go nuts on stealth since you will be so far away that they won't see you anyway.

Is there any merit to that claim? Otherwise I was thinking of going 100 (or close) in Sneak but is that wasting points?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It's not wasting points.**

100 stealth will get you much closer than reasonable sniping distance. However, there are quite a few enclosed areas in which you'll have to get a lot closer than normal sniping distances just to be able to see your targets (inside vaults, for example), and higher stealth will definitely help you there.

Furthermore, the number of points a high-intelligence character will receive by hitting the level cap is enough to max out almost every skill. There are actually a lot more skill points available than there are skills worth maxing; maxing sneak is hardly a waste of points, compared to, say, maxing survival in a non-hardcore playthrough.

Comment: Stealing is always very useful too, sneak was one of the first skills I maxed.